# Return All Pages of RSS

Tags: python, rss, beautifulsoup

I am grabbing the xml from rss pages using python.  I am using beautiful soup to parse the xml.

The input is the rss xml pages are found at http://stackoverflow.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss for example.

I use several blogs with a similar format to the link above, and the xml for each can be found at `/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss`

the data for Each URL is downloaded using urllib2 and saved in the variable `xml`

My python code then uses beautiful soup to to parse the xml

```
bs = BeautifulSoup(xml)
items = bs.rss.channel.findAll("item")
print len(items) #returns 25 for any site
```

I believe I am returning only the first page.

How can I return all pages and easily find the number of pages per URL?

for example: len(pages)=number of pages

Comment: It seems you will need to request all pages in the python script that you use to grab the XML from RSS pages. You need to elaborate on your question a bit with sample input and expected output...

Comment: @vikramls Yes that appears to be what I am looking for.  I have updated the question

Answer (score 2):

RSS/Atom Pagination is not a standard... so everyone does it different (for those who do!), which means you'll have trouble doing what you're trying to do.

RSS should probably seen more as a "prospective" tool: not something to get past content, but to get future content: if you start subscribing to the feed, you'll be able to keep track of things from now on and as long as the feed stays up.

Comment: I just was looking to grab RSS feeds as a whole for several blogs, Is it difficult to access the next page of 25 items? Would there be any advantage to using Atom?